# How to combine two queries in Solr with ComplexPhraseQueryParser?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

1. When I search in Solr 4.0 with the following two filter queries separately, it works as expected.

   `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}employeeName_t:"Mike R*"`

   `empDate_dt:[2016-10-10T00:00:00Z TO 2016-10-10T23:59:59Z]`
2. But I am not getting proper search results when I combine these two queries(Irrespective of the order).

   - `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}employeeName_t:"Mike R*" AND empDate_dt:[2016-10-10T00:00:00Z TO 2016-10-10T23:59:59Z]`

   This query gives me zero search results in Solr

   **"response":  {
   "numFound":0,
   "start":0, 
   "maxScore":0,
   "docs":[]
   }**

   - `empDate_dt:[2016-10-10T00:00:00Z TO 2016-10-10T23:59:59Z] AND {!complexphrase inOrder=true}employeeName_t:"Mike R*"`

   Whereas change in query order gives me parse exception as follows

   **"error":{
   "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError:     org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot
   parse 'employeeName_t:\"Mike': Lexical error at line 1, column 21. Encountered:  after : \"\\"Mike\"",code:400
   }**

   Using *ComplexPhraseQueryParser* for partial search in solr.Need to use both queries.Any suggestions to this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use fq parameter.

docs are retrieved with query as :"Mike R*" and filtered with dates specified in fq parameter.

Example:

```
q={!complexphrase inOrder=true}employeeName_t:"Mike R*"&fq=empDate_dt:["2016-10-10T00:00:00Z" TO "2016-10-10T23:59:59Z"]
```

Comment: Both are used as filter queries[Multiple filters].Is it possible to use them both in fq and make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, SOLR (>4.5) supports, fq=(field1:value1 OR field2:value2). you can use `q=mainQuery(*:*)&fq=({!complexphrase inOrder=true}employeeName_t:"Mike R*" AND empDate_dt:["2016-10-10T00:00:00Z" TO "2016-10-10T23:59:59Z"] )`

Comment: change main query q and operator accordingly.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with date alone.Your query works fine with string,text fields and even integer fields,if given in the second part after complex query.Just not with date.